# selecting items in a listview to choose an keyboard layout from an xml file with each listview item assigned its own specific layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a listview and I want to assign each item its own xml layout.  When I click on each item, I want it to select an xml file which will change the layout of a custom keyboard.  Basically, I want to be able to choose the xml file by clicking the items from the listview, not by manually inserting the name of the xml file I want to be the layout of my keyboard.  What I have tried to do  is use the setContentview method with if statemens in the main activity, but it it requires a xml layout file, and the keyboard layouts are in a seperate xml folder titled "xml".  Here is what it looks like: `setContentView(R.xml.black);`

MainActiviy

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView chl = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.colorselector);
        chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        String[] items = {"black", "brown", "blue", "white", "purple", "grey"};
        Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,items);
        chl.setAdapter(adapter);

        chl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                int item_position=i;
```

Here is the MyKeyboard java class.  The line 
`keyboard = newKeyboard(this, R.xml.black);` is where it is possible to change the keyboard layout with the specific xml file (in this case, the xml file is called "black").  I am currently able to change the keyboard layout,but I have to do it by changing it manually.

```
package com.example.jesse.languageswitcher;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

public class MyKeyboard extends InputMethodService
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener{


    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.black);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }


    private void playClick(int keyCode){
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch(keyCode){
            case 32:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            case 10:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch (primaryCode) {
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                caps = !caps;
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;
            default:
                char code = (char) primaryCode;
                if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but how did I not mention what the problem is?

Comment: I am not getting errors, and it is not doing something else.  I just do know how I would accomplish what I want to acheive so I posted the pertinent code in my project to see if anybody has any ideas on how to achieve what I want using the code I posted.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on what to put in the code?  That is what I am really struggling with.

Comment: I am struggling and that is why I asked the question in the first place.  I am not simply asking  "Can you please write some code for me?".  I am asking if you have any ideas on how to accomplish my goal- which can include making suggestions about changing my code, giving some methods I can use, or showing me some code that would help make it work- SO if full of those types of answers and questions and that is what SO is all about.  Please stop commenting on my question.  It appears as if you are here to waste my time and you have barely contributed anything to the question.